# Tablepress and modal window

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, modal-dialog

heres my code on headers.php using wordpress. im also using twenty-thirteen theme and tablepress plug-in.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="js/jquery-ui.css" />
<script type="text/javascript src="js/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript src="js/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
$( "#dialog103" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,});
$("#103" ).click(function() {
  $( "#dialog103" ).dialog( "open" );
});
});
</script>

<div id="dialog103" title="SECTION 103. Scope and Application">
<p><strong>(a)</strong>The provisions of this Code shall apply..<br></div>
```

and on the tablepress column 1 row 1 cell i have this.

```
<button  id="103">NBC SECT 103</button>
```

when i click on the button nothing happens.
also the text on id #dialog103 appears at the top of my web page. Thats should be on the modal load content.

thanks

Comment: check fiddle your code is working http://jsfiddle.net/fUgaf/7/

Comment: Thanks, Sridhar for the fast reply. it works on fiddle, then why is it not wordking on wordpress? maybe there is something wrong with the code on linking js script file. can you guide me on that. im new to wordpress. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers) "the jQuery library included with WordPress is set to the noConflict() mode". To get your code working, wrap it with:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Inside of this function, $() will work as an alias for jQuery()
});
```